# check who is connected to a specific computer on the network?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

In our network (Active Directory based) we have several (Windows) computers that I can connect via remote desktop.
But when I connect to a pc when someone else is already connected, that person is kicked.

Is there a way to check if someone is connected (and get his name) to a specific computer on the network via a command line?

Comment: Is this an Active Directory-based domain network, or an ad-hoc workgroup-style network?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin it's Active Directory

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using PowerShell; I needed to do this for largely the same reason. I have a modified version of [Brian Wilhite's `Get-LastLogon` script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-LastLogon-Determining-283f98ae); my version is somewhat stripped down because I don't need to worry about anything earlier than Windows 7 on our network. I should note that my environment guarantees that any computer I run this on will be running PowerShell 4 or 5.1; if you are running PowerShell Core (6 or later), you will probably have to modify it to change WMI calls to CIM calls, at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

You can try command [qwinsta /server: *servername*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/qwinsta). It will display information about sessions on a Remote Desktop Session Host server.